# How Maven knows what remote repositories to access and check?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Let's say i'm adding Spring dependency to my Maven project:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/4.2.1.RELEASE

To my pom.xml, the following will be added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

How my Maven will know from where exactly the artifact will be fetched? I didn't setup anything in maven settings.xml besides our enterprise Artifactory repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several official Central repositories and proxies. (See [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)) and Maven knows them by default.

Specifying something in your *settings.xml* will just add some to the list.

A convenient way to search through the Central repository is to go to: [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org)

Comment: Thanks. So the central repositories and proxies predefined in Maven (except the ones I manually add to settings.xml), and could be changed according to Maven decisions?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't see the last part of your post. Yes the central repository is predefined in Maven. However, Artifactory also knows about the central repository (It probably come with a few other locations as well) so when you specify your own repo in the settings.xml, Artifactory should take precedence over the predefined ones

Comment: The idea is that you should specify new locations in Artifactory instead of your local Maven. Providing easier config for new comers and more efficient bandwith